# How to convert any navigation property Into JSON format? And, how to make JSON Schema from multiple navigation property?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, jsonschema, jetbrains-rider

I want to create JSON Schema from different classes, which I mentioned all below.

This is the **Schedule** Class.

```
public class Schedule : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<OperativeSchedule> OperativeSchedules { get; set; } //navigation
        public virtual IEnumerable<SchedulePanels> SchedulePanels { get; set; } //navigation

        public int HolidayScheduleId { get; set; } //FK
        public virtual IEnumerable<HolidaySchedule> HolidaySchedules { get; set; } //navigation
        
}
```

This is the **OperativeSchedule** Class.

```
public class OperativeSchedule : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Operative Operative { get; set; }
}
```

This is the **Operative** Class.

```
public class Operative : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual OperativeSchedule OperativeSchedule { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I build my **JSON Schema**.

```
{
  "name": "Weekly Schedule",
    
  "operativeSchedules": [
    {
            "scheduleId": 1,
                "schedule": {
                        "name":"Week Schedule",
                        "operativeSchedules": [
                            "Morning Operative",
                            {
                                "ScheduleId": 1,
                                "Schedule":{ 
                                     Name" : "Weekly Schedule"
                                 }                          
                            }
                        ]
                    
                }
    }
        
  ],
```

Now, when I'm debugging my code, I'm receiving the error as you can see.

> ```
> {
>   "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
>   "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
>   "status": 400,
>   "traceId": "00-470af684f2b9779984917fb5a90d0df5-2812a4ec9be9d4f8-00",
>   "errors": {
>       "request": [
>           "The request field is required."
>       ],
>       "$.operativeSchedules[0].schedule.operativeSchedules[0]": [
>           "The JSON value could not be converted to Domain.Models.Schedules.OperativeSchedule. Path: $.operativeSchedules[0].schedule.operativeSchedules[0] | LineNumber: 9 | BytePositionInLine: 28."
>       ]
>   }
> }
> ```

Any, Idea on this one, why Its not coverting `public virtual IEnumerable<OperativeSchedule> OperativeSchedules { get; set; }`property?

Here, from this block of code,

```
"operativeSchedules": [
                            "Morning Operative",
                            {
                                "ScheduleId": 1,
                                "Schedule":{ 
                                   "Name" : "Weekly Schedule"
                                 }                          
                            }
                        ]
```

I tried to use this, but It seems the code is not working. I'm expecting to make JSON schema out of this, which work perfectly.

```
operativeSchedules": [ "Morning Operative" ]
```

Please can anyone help resolve this error? Any kind of help would be appriciated. Thank you.

Comment: in your example you have NAME without starting quote. and closing }

Comment: populate class with data and use JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented) on it to create a schema example

Comment: What are you using to do this generation?  Have you looked at [JsonSchema.Net.Generation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net.Generation) (my library)?  ([docs](https://docs.json-everything.net/schema/schema-generation/))